# How capture remote ssh output into a variable

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, scripting

I would like to know how to capture the output of this command into a variable

ssh -q $ssh_host  'ps -eo comm,lastcpu'

Once the information is captured, I want to check the variable if it returned more then one result and label it

Example

rpciod/0          0
   rpciod/1          1
   rpciod/2          2
   rpciod/3          3

After processing I want the output to be

it adds the hostname and puts the output on separate line, removing /1 /2 if it find it

Hostname1 being the value of $ssh_host

hostname1  rpciod          0
 hostname1  rpciod         1
 hostname1  rpciod          2
 hostname1  rpciod         3

Comment: variable=$(ssh -q $ssh_host 'ps -eo comm,lastcpu')

Comment: I have tried that but it seems not to work, I need to catch the output and amend it as per above table.

Comment: Once you have the variable filled with the output from the command, you can process it with tools such as sed, awk, etc.

Comment: @lgeorget If further processing of the output is to be done, you should _not_ put it into a variable but pipe it to the next processing stage.

Comment: Please expand this question by stating you've tried what's in the dupe, describe *exactly* what you did, what output you were expecting, and what you got and I'll support a re-open vote.

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same as with any other command:

```
VAR=$(ssh -q $ssh_host 'ps -eo comm,lastcpu')
```